# How to uninstall all unused versions of a macports package at once

Tags: macos, macports

When maintaining macports packages, I prefer to remove old packages when I replace them with new ones. However, over time as packages are upgraded, you end up with problems like:

```
$ sudo port uninstall -f postgresql83
--->  The following versions of postgresql83 are currently installed:
--->    postgresql83 @8.3.3_0
--->    postgresql83 @8.3.7_0
--->    postgresql83 @8.3.8_1 (active)
Error: port uninstall failed: Registry error: Please specify the full version as recorded in the port registry.
```

Is there a macports command to remove all versions of a package at once?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to uninstall all the old (non-active) versions try this:

```
port -y -u uninstall
  # if you like what you see, change “port -y” to “sudo port”
```

If you mean that you want to uninstall all the versions (non-active and active) of (e.g.) the `postgresql83` port, then try this:

```
port -y uninstall installed and postgresql83
  # if you like what you see, change “port -y” to “sudo port”
```

Comment: That worked for me, too bad port doesn't handle dependency updates to postgres84 automatically though.

Comment: @Dana the Sane If you mean removing packages that depend on postgres84 automatically, you can use the --follow-dependents argument.

Comment: @Nick I'll try that next time I uninstall something.

Comment: The second approach works fine for me, but the first one with `-u` seems to give the same warning about multiple versions being installed as if I hadn't used `-u` at all

Comment: These commands don't work (on Mac OSX Mavericks).

Comment: `port -u uninstall` is equivalent to `port uninstall inactive`, in case you wondered. Also @bzero: Yes, they do. And you can trust me on that, I'm a MacPorts dev.

Comment: Thanks for this, maybe what @bzero meant is that you have to use sudo port -y as well since it wont let you touch the index without it.  Even on dry-run.  Using Yosemite now fyi and still works.

Answer (score 46):

```
sudo port uninstall inactive
```

This will remove your inactive ports.